# Unable to set up Auth0 React Native SDK. As soon as I install it and add the manifestPlaceholders, my build stops building

Tags: android, react-native, auth0

I am following the [Auth0 React Native SDK Documentation](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/react-native/interactive) and have ran the following command in order to install the SDK

```
yarn add react-native-auth0
```

Then I opened my `build.gradle` file, found the `defaultConfig` and added the following line:

```
manifestPlaceholders = [auth0Domain: "{yourDomain}", auth0Scheme: "${applicationId}.auth0"]
```

With my own value:

```
manifestPlaceholders = [auth0Domain: "dev-mydomain.us.auth0.com", auth0Scheme: "com.test.testApp.auth0"]
```

com.test.testApp is my applicationId and I've replaced my actual domain number with mydomain in this example.Unfortunately, as soon as I do that, my application stops building and begins throwing random errors stating that a lot of my modules were compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. Example of this error:

```
/Users/Me/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/d988da825e8e248c6c963416e5d1125f/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
```

Anyone have any idea what's going on? Could it be related to the fact that I have different build types and flavors? I just don't understand why would I be getting such error if that was the case though.